# C++ find all pointer arithmetic in file

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

There are several large C++ source files. We need to find all pointer arithmetic operations in these files. Is it possible to do this task automatically?

Is it possible to disable pointer arithmetic in some compiler and get list of errors?

Comment: Maybe if you're willing to hack an open-source compiler? (Clang?) Seems like a lot of work though -- what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: We develop application for not usual CPU. Pointers in it are not numbers - they are structures. And arithmetic operations are not correct. Unfortunately compiler does not know about this fact and generate usual pointer arithmetic code.

Comment: 1) your compiler is not standart C++/C (pointer arithmetic must work for any pointer) OR 2) You use structure as pointer, but does not write operator++(), operator--() ... for this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "no".

However, if you had software that could fully parse and understand your source code, that software would be able to determine this information. This is a major undertaking if you were to write such software yourself.

Comment: With Clang it is not a major undertaking.

Comment: Then you would not be writing the software yourself. At least, not all of it.

Answer (score 3):

Make a copy of your code and change all pointer variables to (void *).
Then all pointer arithmetic will get compile errors.